# Error al querer obtener el ID mediante método GET en PHP

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]   Trato de obtener el id mediante metodo GET pero me lanza un error de que el id esta indefinido.

```
  <?php // Incluimos la consulta a la BD

   include "conexion.php";
    $id=$_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id=$id";
    $re = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
 while ($f=mysqli_fetch_array($re,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 ?>

  <div class="producto">
  <center>
  <img src="./productos/<?php echo $f['imagen'];?>"><br>
  <span><?php echo $f['nombre'];?></span><br>
 <span>Precio: <?php echo $f['precio'];?></span><br>
 <a href="./detalles.php?id=<?php echo $f['id'];?>">ver</a>
 </center>
 </div>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: Hola verifica que estés pesando bien el valor del id por el url. Seria bueno que colocaras ese fragmento para revisar.  En caso que lo estés pasando por formulario verifica que no estés usando, post en vez de get

Comment: Si como te dice @YoelRodriguez verifica que en tu envio si se este enviando como GET y que desde ahí no vaya vacio por eso del lado de tu PHP te llega indefinido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El parametro `id` no está llegando, lo puedes comprobar de esta forma:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !is_null($_GET['id']) ) // la variable si existe y no tiene valor nulo.
    echo $_GET['id'];
else
   echo "no hay variable id";
```

Un ejemplo básico del formulario:

```
<form action="/url/al-archivo/archivo.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <button type="submit" >enviar</button>
</form>
```

Para pasarlo mediante un link:

```
<a href="/url/al-archivo/archivo.php?id=aqui-va-el-valor">
    Ir a leer a la base de datos
</a>
```

Comment: si ya vi, alguna forma de poder pasar el id?

Comment: con el ejemplo del formulario que puse puede, o lo quieres pasar mediante un link?

Comment: Si, estoy tratando de hacer un carrito de compras y el id lo quiero enviar mediante el link.

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

No estas pasando el parámetro "id"

- Verifica que en tu petición no estés poniendo "ID" o "Id"
- Verifica que este usando GET y no POST

**Editado:**
EL problema esta en el codigo que genera tu link:
intenta con

```
<a href=<?php echo "./detalles.php?id=".$f['id'];?>>ver</a>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Te comento que ya lo hice de esa manera y me manda un error de que el id esta indefinido no sea si siga siendo la parte de la obtencion del id o la consulta.. editare la pregunta con el error

Comment: que sucede cuando le pasas el argumento desde la url?

por ejemplo:

localhost/lepanier/detalles.php?id=1

Comment: ps me manda a la pagina de detalles pero no me muestra nada, aparece en blanco la pagina

Comment: pero si en lugar de 1 pones un id valido de tu base de datos?, que url te marca el hipervinculo que generas desde el php `<a href=<?php echo "./detalles.php?id=".$f['id'];?>>ver</a>`?

Comment: Bueno es que en realidad si tienen esos id por cuestiones de rapidez.. http://localhost/lepanier/detalles.php?id=10

Comment: cuando entras directo de la url ya no te marca el error `undefined index`?

Comment: No.. me manda la pagina en blanco.. anexo la imagen

Comment: que te marca tu error_log?